# What will happen, if in my Kafka ecosystem one partition is full (hashing based approach )and now still receiving new msg for same key

Tags: java, apache-kafka

scenario: If a Kafka cluster has a topic 'TopicA' with 2 brokers, each having 4 partitions, and a producer is consistently sending messages with key 'A' at a high volume. If one partition on a particular broker becomes full due to these messages, what happens to new messages with key 'A'? How does Kafka handle this situation, and where will the new messages be directed?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your replication factor. Partition count does not matter. 2 brokers does not imply 2 replicas are available for any partition.

If the broker disk becomes full from one partition, that broker will crash, and the leader partition becomes unavailable, causing another replica to be elected (if one exists). Kafka does not recover or handle this scenario